# Solving $f(x+y)-f(x)=yf'\Big(x+ \dfrac y{2}\Big),\forall x,y\in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(x+y)-f(x)=yf'\Big(x+ \dfrac y{2}\Big),\forall x,y\in \mathbb R$ , then how do we show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Differentiate with respect to $y$:

$$
f'(x+y) = f'(x+y/2) + y/2 f''(x+y/2)
$$
Now set $y=-2x$
$$
f'(-x) = f'(0) - x f''(0)
$$
Replace $x$ by $-x$ to get it to a recognizable form.
$$
f'(x) = f'(0)+x f''(0)
$$
Integrate to get
$$
f(x) = C + f'(0) x + \frac{1}{2} f''(0) x^2
$$

---

*Added in response to comments about existence of $f''$ *

*We have to show that $f''$ exists*.

Letting $z = x + y/2$ we have

$$f'(z) = \frac{f(z+y/2)-f(z-y/2)}{y}$$

Fix $y \neq 0$. Clearly the right hand side is differentiable with respect to $z$. Hence, so is the left hand side

Comment: any symmetric function has this property so you cannot conclude such a thing from this alone.

Comment: mea culpa. I was not thinking (not a first for me!) Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Should be correct now.

Comment: Better. +1. Though it couldn't hurt to explain why $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: You are going to make me work, aren't you? Too tired and sleepy for that. It is 3:53 AM here.

Comment: @WimC : If $f'$ is continuous, then $f$ is twice-differentiable, but is it obvious from the given conditions that $f'$ is continuous?

Comment: Added another answer to show that $f$ is twice differentiable. Amazing what sleep can do to your brains!

Comment: @user44197: you could have just written $f'(x)=f\bigg(x+\dfrac1{2}\bigg)-f\bigg(x-\dfrac1{2}\bigg)$

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a much more elegant way to do this, but here's where tinkering got me:

Applying $\frac{d}{dy}-\frac{d}{dx}$ to the functional equation gives us $f'(x) = f'(x+y/2) - (y/2) f''(x+y/2)$.  Setting $x=0$ and $z=y/2$ gives $f'(z) - zf''(z) = f'(0)$.

Differentiating this once gives us $f''(z) - f''(z) - zf'''(z) = -zf'''(z) = 0$, so $f'''(z)=0$ for $z\neq 0$.  Hey, what do you know, it's a polynomial.